# Python - put each line into a variable

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and I have attempted to search for a solution but cannot seem to find my exact question.

Question is how to place each line from a file being read into a variable for future use?

I have a file reading in great, and i transform it so that its ready to go but i'm not sure how to proceed from here.

the output is as follows:

```
Who was the fastest formula one driver in the previous race?
VET
HAM
RIC
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
for line in PopQuiz:
    Question = line[0]
    Answer1 = line[1]  
    Answer2 = line[1]   
    Answer3 = line[1]
```

Then from there I can use a variable in the rest of the application.

Comment: `Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 = PopQuiz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to read the entire file into a list:

```
lines = PopQuiz.readlines()
```

You can then access list elements if needed. If you really need to put the lines into variables, you can do that with a simple assignment:

```
Question = lines[0]
Answers = lines[1:]
```

In the above example, "Question" will contain the first line and "Answers" will contain a list of answers. You may also wish to strip trailing newline characters from the values. You can do that with a list comprehension:

```
Question = lines[0].strip()
Answers = [x.strip() for x in lines[1:]]
```

Comment: Thank you this is great, i didn't know i can use [0] to query from a list!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
all_lines = []

with open('file.txt') as fr:
  for line in fr:
    all_lines.append(line)
```

Then, since you have a question on the first line:

```
question = all_lines[0]
answers = all_lines[1:]
```

Comment: What is `answers` and where does it's `all_lines()` method come from?